# Colon instead of comma separator when using NumberFormatter::formatCurrency() for Swedish

Tags: php, locale, currency, numberformatter

I have the following piece of code that formats a price for a given locale and currency (Italian in this example, normally this is a method).

```
$locale = "it";
$currency = "USD";
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter($locale, \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);

$priceInCents = 1100;
return $formatter->formatCurrency($priceInCents / 100, $currency);
```

This returns:

```
US$ 12,29
```

However when using the Swedish locale (sv) the code returns the price with a colon:

```
12:29 US$
```

This does not happen when I use the full locale "se_SE" but unfortunately we only have the two letter version available. Any ideas? Is this a bug?

Comment: How about using `$formatter->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::MONETARY_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, ',');` (maybe only as a special case for `se`?)

Comment: No, this won't help. Especially if there are other locales that use different separators. Currently I'm just assuming a Norwegian locale for the currency formatting as a workaround.

Comment: What did you find @Fred? I ahd the same issue! https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: Afair I pretty much tested all known locales in batch and wrote hardcoded fallbacks for the ones that were failing.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested: you can use

```
NumberFormatter::MONETARY_GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for gravedigging.

The OP actually got the correct formatting of the monetary value, according to the 'sv' locale. Colon is often used as (currency) decimal seperator in Sweden. In fact they often use colon in abbreviations too.

Basicly the locale code consists of a language code [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) and a region code [ISO 3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) (usually in uppercase letters) seperated by an underscore (or a dash if dealing with Javascript).

['sv'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes#sv) is the correct language code for swedish language, so when the OP was using the locale code 'se_SE' the language actually used (['se'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes#se)) was the  [Northern Sámi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_S%C3%A1mi) language (spoken by a minority in parts of Norway, Finland and Sweden) which does use a full stop as decimal seperator.

It appears as if the OP don't actually want the output localized, or at least not if it uses 'different seperators', which many do. Faking a locale to fit specific a scheme, is probably the wrong way to go about it, but as others have pointed out, there are ways to forceably change seperators. It sort of defys the point of localizing in the first place, though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).